# When can I promote an advisor?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

In update 1.23, the one released alongside Cradle of Civilization, advisors were given personal religions and cultures and the ability to be upgraded. It seems like I can almost never upgrade an advisor though. I've seen it a few times, but right now I can't upgrade any of them.

The changelog says that they must be of a promoted or same-group culture, and all of my advisors are of my primary culture, but the button isn't showing up still. Is there another requirement for promoting advisors or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Haven't played with the new patch yet, so just speculation: a) Maybe both religion and culture must be accepted, i.e. state religion + accepted culture. or b) you don't have enough money to upgrade the advisor, so the button is grayed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need Cradle of Civilization installed. When The DLC was first released in November there was a bug (a good one) that allowed promotion without the DLC installed, but it has since been fixed. The advisor's culture must be your ruler's culture as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [EU4 Wiki](https://eu4.paradoxwikis.com/Advisor#Promote_advisor), it is possible to promote an advisor that shares your ruler's culture at the cost of 60 times the monthly cost (or 5 years of salary). I haven't tested it myself, but my guess is that you don't have enough ducats to pay for the update, so the button is not available.

Answer (score -1):

I was asking this myself whats going on (playing Ulm right now, one city tall challenge xD) and just saw i could promote my mil advisor, but not my two other advisors; I've checked the culture/religion right now, all three of them are male, protestant swabians.

I don't know exactly what's going on or why I can only promote my mil advisor (btw their ages are 53 - 35 - 52 in order adm-dipl-mil), but I have one guess: I'm a republic with a 1-1-4 leader right now (yeah, I need to increase my 22 force limit with my little city Ulm so I'm going for quantity right now after def+off xD) and my advisors are 1-1-3 right now ... so I think it is possible that you can only promote to the max of your monarch/leader/bürgermeister? I'm checking that right now: Hm, well, I could promote him to 4, but not 5 but the tooltip said that I had not enouch money ... so I'm not sure if that is a limit for it too ... ah yeah, the button wasn't greyed out, the click just didn't work.

anyways, that is my input here, if someone knows for sure, it would help ^^

Comment: How does this answer the question?